# styling a TextNode

Tags: javascript, dom, textnode

I'm making a simple multiple choice program using radio buttons.
When the student gets an answer wrong I can put an X after her choice, but how do I make the X red?
Thanks for any help,
Gerard

```
<body> 

<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1756-1819,Berlioz" 
             onclick = "radioProcessor(this)" />      &nbsp; 1756-1819

<script>
function radioProcessor(theRadio){
        theRadio.nextSibling.nodeValue = theRadio.nextSibling.nodeValue + " X";
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Say, thanks Andree but that didn't work.  I think because a TextNode holds text, not other elements (like a span).  However thanks to your idea this is possible -

```
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1756-1819,Berlioz" 
             onclick = "radioProcessor(this)" /> <span>&nbsp; 1756-1819</span>

<script>
function radioProcessor(theRadio){
        console.log(theRadio.nextElementSibling); // prints [object Text]
        theRadio.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("style","color:red");
        theRadio.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 
                          theRadio.nextElementSibling.innerHTML + " X";
}
```

It's closer, but I'd like to have only the "X" in red :-)  It also continues adding X's every time the radio button is pressed!

Comment: i updated my code and it works even when clicking twice on the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Even when clicking twice on the radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1756-1819,Berlioz"
             onclick = "radioProcessor(this)" />     <span id="value"> &nbsp; 1756-1819</span>

<script>
function radioProcessor(theRadio){
  var xAdded = document.getElementsByClassName("incorrect").length;
  if(!xAdded) {
    var result = document.createElement('span');
    result.setAttribute("class", "incorrect");
    result.innerHTML = theRadio.nextSibling.nodeValue + " X";
    var value = document.getElementById("value");
    value.parentNode.insertBefore(result, value.nextSibling);
  }


}
</script>
```